# With beamer, xcolor fails to read dvipsnam.def in Ubuntu 22.04 TeXLive 2022

Tags: beamer, color

The following basic beamer document fails to compile with `pdfTeX` on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop with TeX Live 2022:

```
\documentclass[xcolor = dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor = NavyBlue}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage

\href{mailto:climatestudent@climatestudent.org}{climatestudent@climatestudent.org} % not a working address
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error obtained in the corresponding `log` file is

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `NavyBlue'.
```

However, "NavyBlue" is a colour defined in `dvipsnam.def`, a file present on my system at the correct location. In particular, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with TeX Live 2019, the same `TeX` sample compiles with pdfTeX and yields a PDF document as expected. Comparing the log files between the two systems, the primary difference regarding loading the xcolor package is that the following line occurs with TeX Live 2019, whereas no corresponding entry is produced with TeX Live 2022

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
```

Further information about the installation and packages from the log file (in both cases, TeX Live was installed using `apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`):

On Ubuntu 22.04:

pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.1.23)

Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

[side note: I'm not sure how I ended up with TeX Live 2022/**dev**/Debian. Is this standard with Ubuntu 22.04? And is it possibly relevant here?]

On Ubuntu 20.04:

pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.31)

Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

I've found no indication of any corresponding bugs posted anywhere, but I may have not searched in the right places.

Comment: Try with `\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\documentclass{beamer}`, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/759

Comment: Great, that works!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I'm going to blame !g, searching "xcolor dvipsnames not working" doesn't provide a link to the Github issue on pg. 1

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: ... and I'm going to blame ubuntu for not giving you an up-to-date beamer version :)

Comment: Deleting is not necessary. Duplicates act as signposts so that all these ubuntu users with ancient beamer versions will find the solution :)